# Unique option selection from drop down?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have an html page which contains 10 dropdowns each having option from 1 to 10. 
how do i assign options uniquely to all dropdowns .e.g. If i select 1 from dropdown 1 then that particular option is removed from other dropdowns.
if i diselect anyone then number of that particular dropdown again added in options of dropdowns.

Comment: Sorry it;s not clear what you want to do

Comment: I have multiple dropdowns in a page. which contains similar options. i want to select unique options for each dropdown. if i select any option in any dropdown then that option must be removed from other dropdowns so they all do not get common option.

Comment: Suppose you have 2 dropdown with similar values 1 to 10, then when you select 1 from 1st dropdwn then 1 must be removed from the 2nd  drpdwn?

Comment: yeah and i have to also give option of clear option in each dropdown on doing clear the selected option of that dropdown is added in options of unselected dropdowns.

Comment: Have you done any code?? If yes provide plunker

Comment: that fiddle does not match the description at all. it only has one dropdown with 3 options that you can add single values to

Comment: this is the fiddle link i have done recently https://jsfiddle.net/ashish_pbh/MTfRD/1766/
but a problem is coming as after splice selected values are not displaying in the dropdown. any solution for show values in this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model='selectedNumber' ng-change="adv(selectedNumber);" ng-options='number for number in numbers'></select>
num:   {{selectedNumber}}
<select ng-model='selected' ng-options="number for number in num"></select>
num:   {{selected}}
<button ng-click="add()" >add</button>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {    
  $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  $scope.num = angular.copy($scope.numbers);
  $scope.selectedNumber = $scope.numbers[0];
  //$scope.selected = $scope.num[0];

  $scope.add=function(){
  $scope.num = angular.copy($scope.numbers);
}

 $scope.adv = function(selectedNumber){
 $scope.num = angular.copy($scope.numbers);
 // $scope.selected = $scope.numbers[selectedNumber];   
 var a = $scope.num.splice(selectedNumber-1, 1);  
}

 $scope.num = angular.copy($scope.numbers);
}
```

Hope this is the one that you wanted.

Comment: this is the fiddle link i have done recently https://jsfiddle.net/ashish_pbh/MTfRD/1766/

 but a problem is coming as after splicing selected values are not displaying in the dropdown. any solution for show values in this

Comment: Is the code provided above not as per the requirement

Comment: no that is not matching with my exact requirement hence i have done in myself   jsfiddle.net/ashish_pbh/MTfRD/1766 
but a small problem is coming as numbers are not shown in dropdown after selection but for that i have created a <span> and shown the number in that span after selection.